# Shapeless Json parsing by LabelledGeneric

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, circe

I'm new to Shapeless and sorry if I can't see easy solution.

Imagine we have data case class

```
case class Test(x: Int, y: String, z: Double) extends Row
```

Json (doesn't contain all fields of case class)

```
{ "x": 10, "y": "foo" }
```

and special case class to decode json to

```
case class UpdateRequest[T <: Row](updates: List[Update[T]])
```

Update[Row] is a sealed trait to help execute composable update in slick, it's huge to post here and in fact it's not about the problem.

The goal is to parse json (I use circe) and check if each json field exists in case class provided as a type parameter to UpdateRequest and try to decode json value with type gotten from case class.

For example I need working something like

```
parse(json).as[UpdateRequest[Test]] ...
```

So we need custom decoder mixed with shapeless.

This is overall description, if you show full solution would be awesome, but current problem is I can't find by name particular field from fields list

For example I can decode particular field like

```
def decode[T, U](s: (Symbol with Tagged[U], T), c: HCursor)(implicit decoder: Decoder[T]) = {
  c.downField(s._1.name).as[T]
}

val test = Test(1, "foo", 1.5)
val lg = LabelledGeneric[Test]
val fields = Fields[lg.Repr].apply(lg.to(test))

decode(fields.head)
```

But how to go over all fields and find by name first?

I assume it might be like

```
def decode[...](fields: [...], c: HCursor, fieldName: String)(implicit decoder: Decoder[T]) = {
  // try to find field by name, if exists try to decode
 ...
}
```

Thank you for help in advance.

**EDIT**

Step by step simplified example.

We have data classes which represent Rows in DB.

```
trait Row
case class User(id: Int, age: Int, name: String) extends Row
case class SomeOtherData(id: Int, field1: List[String], field2: Double) extends Row
...
```

We have API that accepts any json on routes like

```
PUT http://192.168.0.1/users/:userId
PUT http://192.168.0.1/other/:otherId
...
```

For example we call on PUT http://192.168.0.1/users/:userId next json

```
{ "age": 100 }
```

We have special class to decode json to

```
UpdateRequest[T <: Row](updates: List[Update[T]])
```

where "updates" is going to be like

```
List(
  Update((_: User).age, 100)
)
```

Full example with this approach you can find at https://www.missingfaktor.me/writing/2018/08/12/composable-table-updates-in-slick/

But once again, it doesn't really matter what it is going to be in the end of the race, because the cause of the problem is other.

So, we parse incoming json as UpdateRequest[User].
1) We go over all fields in Json and try to find each in LabelledGeneric[User]
2) If the field is found then we try to decode to found field's type with circe. Otherwise DecodingFailure.

It might be like (types and implementation are not right, just an example to show the idea)

```
object UpdateRequest {
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.ops.record._ 

  def decode[T, U](s: (Symbol with Tagged[U], T), c: HCursor)(implicit decoder: Decoder[T]) = {
    c.downField(s._1.name).as[T]
  }

  implicit def decoder[R <: Row, HL <: HList]()(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[R, HL]): Decoder[UpdateRequest[R]] = new Decoder[UpdateRequest[R]] {

    final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[UpdateRequest[R]] = {
      c.keys match {
        case Some(keys) =>
         // we got "age" key from json
         // for each json key we try to find field in LabelledGeneric's Repr
         // (maybe we need Fields here instead)
         // so we found "age" in case class User and determine the type is Int
         // and then try to decode to Int
         val field = ... //found field from Repr
         for {
           age <- decode(field, c)
         } yield ...

         // and after make it as UpdateRequest[Row] (not needed to implement, the problem is above)

        case None => Left(DecodingFailure("Empty json", Nil))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It seems that task that you are trying to complete doesn't fit shapeless very well as there is no type information in a good shape available in json object. What you can do is to convert your Json object to `List[Any]` containing all your field values and then try to convert it to `HList` passing type information about this list during conversion like `list.toHlist[Int :: String :: Double :: HNil]` . Of course, you need to get this HList type out of the case class first. This conversion may fail or succeed depends on what you actually have in your `List[Any]`.

Comment: I don't need to know type of field in Json object. I need to find it in Fields from a case class provided as type parameter in UpdateRequest[A].

When we use circe auto derivation we don't have types in json object, but it works right? 

The goal is to parse json (I use circe) and check if each json field exists in case class provided as a type parameter to UpdateRequest and try to decode json value with type gotten from case class.

Comment: Why are you exposing your persistence layer implementation (Slick) inside your JSON model class? This seems like a design flaw - what if you move away from Slick?

Comment: I didn't ask about anything about design. Read again carefully if you want to help me regarding the problem, otherwise what if tomorrow won't come?

Comment: it's quite tricky to understand what you actually trying to achieve. Are you trying to get list of field names out of case class then check if there is a specific field in there?  In you last `decode` method stub.. do you need a kind of HList structure containing field names and check if this structure contains `fieldName` passed in last parameter? Is this code helps you `val labl = LabelledGeneric[Foo];
    val names = Keys[labl.Repr].apply.toList.map(_.name)` ?

Comment: I'm also finding it a little difficult to understand what you're asking for. If you could provide a minimal complete example and inputs it'd be a lot easier to help.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you for coming, I've updated the description, hope it's clear now. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I've updated the description, please take a look again

Comment: @RomanGulyaev Have you seen circe-generic's incomplete decoders? https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/06/21/deriving-incomplete-type-class-instances/

Comment: @TravisBrown I just took a brief look there and it looks great, but seems I have to know missing fields in arriving Json and have to provide them in function to create an full filled instance of case class. In my case I don't know particular incoming fields, Json could be different and in fact I don't need to create an instance of Row. I just need to have this fields decoded properly to convert them into Update[Row] and into Slick Query further. Update[Row] only stores the type of Row for creating Slick Query and making new Shape if another Update[Row] provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly your case, but it seems very close to what you need. Probably you can use the idea. I added some stubs to make the code works out of the box without dependencies to circle. The idea was to iterate over case case fields instead of fields from json. The design looks odd, though, as I had to create an instance of case class just to extract field names and types from it without using values from there.

```
trait Decoder[T] {
  def apply(t:String): T
}

implicit val decoderStr: Decoder[String] =  (t) => t
implicit val decoderInt: Decoder[Int] =  (t) => t.toInt
implicit val decoderFloat: Decoder[Double] =  (t) =>  t.toDouble


val c = new {
  def downField(name:String):String = name match {
    case "x" => "5"
    case "y" => "some string"
    case "z" => "2.0"
  }
}

implicit class Stbb (a: String) {
  def as[T](implicit dc: Decoder[T])= dc.apply(a)
}

//end of stubs

import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled._


case class Test(x: Int, y: String, z: Double)
val test = Test(1, "foo", 1.5)

val lg = LabelledGeneric[Test]
val genericTest = lg.to(test)


object mapToEncoded extends Poly1 {

  implicit def toEncodedElements[K,A](implicit key: Witness.Aux[K], dec: Decoder[A])  =
    at[FieldType[K,A]](_ => Some(c.downField(key.value.toString.drop(1)).as[A])))

}

//HList with Option[T] values decoded to proper type
val res = genericTest.map(mapToEncoded)
println(res)
```

You probably just need to replace `Option` with `Decoder.Result` and take care of exceptions in `toEncodedElements`